# How to show text and table in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

How to show h3("Numeric Results") and h3("Summary Statements")? Thank you.

This is my ui.R and server.R.

Below is the code for my ui.R file:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
      tabsetPanel(
        navbarMenu("Means",
               tabPanel("One Mean"),
               tabPanel("Two Means",
                        wellPanel(
                          checkboxInput(inputId = "s1", label = "S1"  , value = FALSE),
                          checkboxInput(inputId = "s2", label = "S2", value = FALSE)
                        ),
                        sidebarPanel(
                          p(strong("Error Rates")),
                          numericInput("alpha", label="Alpha", min=0, max=1,value=0.05),
                          numericInput("power", "Power", 0.8),
                          actionButton("submit","Submit")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Main",
                                     tableOutput("Table"),
                                     verbatimTextOutput("Text")
                            )
                          )
                        )
              )
        ))))
```

Below is the code for my server.R file:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$Table <- renderTable({
    if(input$submit > 0) { 
      h3("Numeric Results")
      output<-data.frame(input$alpha,input$power)
      output
    }
  })

  output$Text<-renderPrint({
    if(input$submit > 0) {
      h3("Summary Statements")
      paste("alpha and power are",input$alpha,"and",input$power)
    }
    })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `Table`, I guess you are not providing a variable to store/display the text and for the `Text`, the `paste` overrides the `h3` code. If you comment the `paste` code, you can see the `h3` code. To have multiple lines of text, you can try something like in the code below.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
  tabsetPanel(
    navbarMenu("Means",
               tabPanel("One Mean"),
               tabPanel("Two Means",
                        wellPanel(
                          checkboxInput(inputId = "s1", label = "S1"  , value = FALSE),
                          checkboxInput(inputId = "s2", label = "S2", value = FALSE)
                        ),
                        sidebarPanel(
                          p(strong("Error Rates")),
                          numericInput("alpha", label="Alpha", min=0, max=1,value=0.05),
                          numericInput("power", "Power", 0.8),
                          actionButton("submit","Submit")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Main",
                                     htmlOutput("header"),
                                     tableOutput("Table"),
                                     htmlOutput("Text")
                            )
                          )
                        )
               )
    ))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$header <- renderText({
    if(input$submit > 0) {
      HTML(paste0("<h3>","Numeric Results","</h3>"))
    }
  })

  output$Table <- renderTable({
    if(input$submit > 0) { 
      output<-data.frame(input$alpha,input$power)
      output
    }
  })

  output$Text<-renderPrint({
    if(input$submit > 0) {
      str1 <- (paste0("<h3>", "Summary Statements", "</h3>"))
      str2 <- paste("alpha and power are",input$alpha,"and",input$power)
      HTML(paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>'))
    }
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```